# How to understand this formula in Lingpipe language model?

Tags: java, nlp

[This is from manual of Lingpipe doc](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/docs/api/com/aliasi/lm/NGramProcessLM.html) in building a language model. But I only partly understand the theory behind it.

I especially do not know the base probability.

[image]

[image]

Here, how to get base p(d). If below is portion of token and their freq in unigram file.

```
ab  20
aba 3
abd 2
abef 2
abkk 3
```

Under such condition, what is lamda(),1-lamda(), extcount, numExtentions and Base P(ab)?
This is one question but they are chained.

Thanks a lot.