# Chunking English words into graphemes corresponding to distinct sounds

Tags: text, nlp, character

How to convert english input word into combinations of graphemes? Is there a library or function that does the job?

What I'm looking for is an algorithm/implementation that splits orthographic words into segments which map to phonemes. That is, the sequence of letters in a word should be broken in between distinct sounds.

To my mind, this would look something like the following:

```
physically --> ph-y-s-i-c-a-ll-y
psychology --> ps-y-ch-o-l-o-g-y
thrush -->     th-r-u-sh
bought --> b-ough-t
chew --> ch-ew
palm --> p-al-m
```

Comment: [grapheme - A fundamental unit of a writing system corresponding to letters in the English alphabet.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grapheme) Can you explain whether what you want is different from just "letters"?

Comment: Where does this definition come from? I ask because I'm wondering why the `i` in 'dictionary' got grouped with `o` rather than `t`. When I've encountered this unit in what might be considered a graphemic context (the [Ghoti example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoti)), it is the `t` and `i` which are grouped as a unit to produce the 'sh' sound.

Comment: @dmh, I am surprised that Ghoti is pronounced as 'fish'. I update example to avoid confusion and extreme irregularities. how would english have created so idiosyncratic sound. Any other words whose  sound deviates remotely, unpredictably and eccentrically from their orthographies?

Comment: @Warren, `ghoti` is a toy example, constructed to show how difficult English orthography is, but I still don't think your question can be answered because it's under-specified. Can you give us a definition for grapheme?

If you Google `split english words into graphemes`, the first result appears to be a paper about mapping English orthography onto a phonemic representation using a Machine Learning approach. Is [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.105.7616&rep=rep1&type=‌​pdf) doing what you're looking for?

Comment: @dmh thanks a lot for suggesting the paper. Again I find it very difficult to do the job. It seems there is no such library. The suggested paper says a conversion based on a modified dictionary(ntc2) that is not available and may not be in public domain. Your suggestion should be listed as one answer to the question.

Comment: @Warren, I'm still trying to figure out exactly what the question is, but I think we've got a decent idea now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for `split english words into graphemes`, the first result appears to be a paper about mapping English orthography onto a phonemic representation using a Machine Learning approach. [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.105.7616&rep=rep1&type=%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bpdf) appears to be doing the kind of thing you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, You have any idea on my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797878/how-to-understand-this-formula-in-lingpipe-language-model ? That seems a little complicated.